# Doctrine 2 query builder and index by

Tags: doctrine-orm

Is it possible to use index by with the doctrine 2 query builder, and if so what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution when using querybuilder, using manual injection of the index by clause -

```
(do you querybuilder statement)
$q  = $q->getQuery()->setDQL(str_replace('WHERE', 'INDEX BY yourIndexValue WHERE', $q->getDQL()));
```

This seems to work for me...

Comment: I realise this is a very old answer, but I would just like to point out that this won't work for queries that don't have any WHERE clause.

Answer (score 44):

Beginning with 2.2, you can now include INDEX BY in your from statement.  If you are adding a from clause,

```
$qb->from($class, $alias, $indexBy);
```

If you already have a from clause that you want to replace, then you can replace it with:

```
$qb->add('from', new Expr\From($class, $alias, $indexBy), false);
```

There's an open pull request to add it to the Repository's createQueryBuilder function as well, so hopefully this will get added soon.

Comment: Hey, I'm writing from 2015, and it's not there yet :-(

Answer (score 7):

For an update. You can do something like this.

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->from($repository->getClassName(), 'a', 'a.id');
$qb->select(a);

$result = new ArrayCollection($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
```

As a result, array collection will contain properly indexed elements.

Answer (score 3):

**The proper syntax and the simplest would be:**

```
$enityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Entity')->createQueryBuilder('entity', 'entity.name')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This would index the result by Entity name field.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a default INDEX BY of a foreign key e.g. "yourIndexValue_id" directly in your mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bar", mappedBy="foo", indexBy="bar_id")
 */
protected $bars;
```

Unfortunately it does not seem to be documented that you have to use the name of the column of the foreign key itself.

[Working with Indexed Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html)

Answer (score -1):

Yes that's possible, using the query builder. A small example, let's assume we want to index by t.someField. Watch the third argument in from method.

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('t.somefield', 't.someOtherField')
    ->setFrom('Entity\Table', 't', 't.someField')
    ->getQuery()
$results = $query->getArrayResult();

//your result will look something like:
$results['somefieldvalue'] = array(array('somefield' => 'value', 'someOtherField' => 'test'));
?>
```

This should work in Doctrine 2.1 at least. In Doctrine 2.0 it's not supported yet. In Doctrine 2.0 it's only supported when you specify it with DQL.

Comment: With Doctrine 2.1.0-DEV, I use `$qb->add('from', 'Entity\Table t INDEX BY t.id');`