# Doctrine QueryBuilder sort results by field priority

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `Service` entity with `title`, `tags` and `description` fields. When searching service with QueryBuilder how can I get results sorted by field priority. For example, when I search term `php` I want get services with `php` in their title at the top of the list, then services with `php` in their tags and services with search term in their description as last.

This is part of my Querybuilder:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('service');
    $qb->leftJoin('service.tags', 'tag');

    $conditions = array($conditions[] = $qb->expr()->eq('service.enabled', true));
    $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->eq('service.category', $categoryId);
    $term = '%' . $term . '%';
    $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like('service.title', "'$term'"),
            $qb->expr()->like('service.description',  "'$term'"),
            $qb->expr()->like('tag.name', "'$term'")
        );

    $conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(), 'andX'), $conditions);

    $qb->where($conditions);
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this would be to perform a series of `UNION` statements and then weed out the duplicates at the same time giving weight.

(Unchecked pseudo-SQL to give you the idea):

```
SELECT id,title,tag,SUM(weight) score
FROM (
   SELECT id,title,tag, 100 as weight FROM service WHERE title LIKE '%foo%'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id,title,tag, 10 as weight FROM service WHERE tags LIKE '%foo%'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id,title,tag, 1 as weight FROM service WHERE description LIKE '%foo%'
) t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY score DESC /* This sort by probably won't work; might need to do it a different way, but you get the idea */
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use native query for this. Ex.:

```
    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

    $sql = "
        select *
        from service s
        where
            s.title like '%xxx%'
            or s.tags like '%xxx%'
            or s.description  like '%xxx%'
        order by 
            s.title like '%xxx%' desc,
            s.tags like '%xxx%' desc,
            s.description  like '%xxx%' desc
    ";

    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('\You\Entity\Service\Class', 's');

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    $data = $query->getResult();

    dump($data);
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html how to use sql insted of dql in orm

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. However my initial query is very complex. and now I am having problem with integrating your solution with query structure I had before

Answer (score 1):

I **would not** try get the desired results in **only one** query. It will be too complicated and you'll spent to much time trying get what you want.

First, I assume you'd like to get a *sorted* Array of `Service` entities like this:

```
/** @var Service[] $results **/
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('YourBundle:YourServiceRepo')->findSerivesByGivenSerchCriteria($yourConditions);
```

so you can simply iterate (foreach) through it

**If it's the case**, concider following:

- create three separate methods whitin your service-repository to get

  1. services with search-criteria in their title - first priority
  2. services with search-criteria in their tags - second priority
  3. services with serach-criteria in their desc - third priority

and in your `findSerivesByGivenSearchCriteria()`method you call all three of them and could combine the found results in any order i'd like

for Example:

```
public function findSerivesByGivenSerchCriteria( $searchTirm ) {
    $foundServicesByTitle = $this->findServicesBySearchCriteriaInTitle( $searachTirm );
    $foundServicesByTag = $this->findServicesBySearchCriteriaInTags( $searchTirm );
    $foundServicesByDesc = $this->findServicesBySearchCriteriaInDesc( $searchTirm );

    // Hier you can combine found results in any order
    $results = [];
    if( false === empty($foundServicesByTitle ) )
    {
    // for example with array_merge ...
    // NOTE: If you choose array_merge() you have to make sure your $foundServicesByTitle, $foundServicesByTag, $foundServicesByDesc have unique array-indexes
    //       And you get Results like
    //       array( 'unique_id_1' => ServiceEntity, 'unique_id_2' => ServiceEntity ... ) 
     $results = array_merge($results, $foundServicesByTitle);
    }
    // .. do the same with other two
    return $results;
}
```

To get the "uniqness" try to combine Doctrine's `INDEX BY` and `HIDDEN`

`INDEX BY` -> http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by

`INDEX BY` in QueryBuilder -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120793/348193

`HIDDEN` -> https://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/

### Why I wouldn't choose the `UNION` way?

Since you work with symfony and doctrine `UNION` isn't the best way. See [How to write UNION in Doctrine 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155288/how-to-write-union-in-doctrine-2-0)

As you can see, `UNION` **isn't supported by Doctrine** and you have to use `NativeQuery` (which could be frustrating with `ResultSetMappingBuilder` and corect mapping and turning raw-results in to desired entities)